# How to make Linux partition for 1TB HDD in here?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

When I installed Ubuntu, I did this sort of partition and where I guess my OS is installed in `/dev/sda2`. I have two extra drives other than that of my `/home`. Does this looks reasonable:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Whenever I install or remove any software (like VLC or anything) it affects the size of swap disk. What would happen if it go full?
Is it ok if I do remove both the other two drives i.e `sda5` and `sda6` and merge them to `/home`?

Note: I don't want a dual boot system. Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hello. Installing apps does not affect the size of the swap. If it is a snap it does go into home. You seem to be confused first you say swap and then you say home.

Comment: @David I just installed VLC media player and I got a notification about `low disk space on FileSystem.root` and checked my `linux-swap` on gparted, it was really filled up, So I had to remove it.

Comment: Again files do not install to swap it is a temp space used when all memory is full. What size did you make the partition for the OS? There is a good chance the VLC you installed is a snap so it went into what ever partition you used for home.

Comment: @David I've linked my gparted screenshot in the post. You can check out the space I allocated.

Comment: Sorry it does not display well for me that is why pictures are not a good idea you could simply say in text the values of each partition.

Comment: I've given 18GB storage for `OS`. For `Swap` it's 487MB. The `home` is given 500GB if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @David Yes as you said, VLC is indeed installed as Snap package. What could be done.

Comment: OK the recommend for the OS in the first place is 25 gig. Swap 1.5 to 2 times the memory  and no specified amount for home. It sounds like you are new to Ubuntu and I am apologetic if you are not but I would have suggested you had let the install set the default partitions since this is the only OS on the machine.

Comment: A reinstall and let the installer partition the drive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135171/discussion-between-gourav-singh-rawat-and-david).

Comment: Opinion: To me, it looks like you have made a classic new-user mistake of *over-partitioning*. Lots of people do that. You read a lot of five-year-old advice and estimated your disk usage based on prior experience with a different OS, and both of those misled you. You have not needed a swap partition for years. A separate /home is only for your data, NOT applications. Advice: Back up your data to some other media, and repartition/reinstall. Use the installer defaults -- they are safe and sane.